# How to store users location into a firebase datebase upon sign up using swift?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, geolocation

hello I am working on an app that will display existing user's within 50 miles of the location of the current user that is using the app.

I already have the basic sign up page working that stores username and email in the fire data base but my question is how do I get the current location of the user that is signing up to save in the firebase database?

here is my code for the signup page:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import Firebase
import GeoFire

class SignUpViewController:UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var usernameField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var emailField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var passwordField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var dismissButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var profileImageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var tapToChangeProfileButton: UIButton!

    var continueButton:RoundedWhiteButton!
    var activityView:UIActivityIndicatorView!

    var imagePicker:UIImagePickerController!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.addVerticalGradientLayer(topColor: primaryColor, bottomColor: secondaryColor)

        continueButton = RoundedWhiteButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 50))
        continueButton.setTitleColor(secondaryColor, for: .normal)
        continueButton.setTitle("Continue", for: .normal)
        continueButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 18.0, weight: UIFont.Weight.bold)
        continueButton.center = CGPoint(x: view.center.x, y: view.frame.height - continueButton.frame.height - 24)
        continueButton.highlightedColor = UIColor(white: 1.0, alpha: 1.0)
        continueButton.defaultColor = UIColor.white
        continueButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleSignUp), for: .touchUpInside)

        view.addSubview(continueButton)
        setContinueButton(enabled: false)

        activityView = UIActivityIndicatorView(activityIndicatorStyle: .gray)
        activityView.color = secondaryColor
        activityView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50.0, height: 50.0)
        activityView.center = continueButton.center

        view.addSubview(activityView)

        usernameField.delegate = self
        emailField.delegate = self
        passwordField.delegate = self

        usernameField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textFieldChanged), for: .editingChanged)
        emailField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textFieldChanged), for: .editingChanged)
        passwordField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textFieldChanged), for: .editingChanged)


        let imageTap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(openImagePicker))
        profileImageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        profileImageView.addGestureRecognizer(imageTap)
        profileImageView.layer.cornerRadius = profileImageView.bounds.height / 2
        profileImageView.clipsToBounds = true
        //tapToChangeProfileButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(openImagePicker), for: .touchUpInside)

        imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = true
        imagePicker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
        imagePicker.delegate = self






    }



    @objc func openImagePicker(_ sender:Any) {
        // Open Image Picker
        self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        usernameField.becomeFirstResponder()
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector:#selector(keyboardWillAppear), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)

    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
        usernameField.resignFirstResponder()
        emailField.resignFirstResponder()
        passwordField.resignFirstResponder()

        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
    }

    override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
        get {
            return .lightContent
        }
    }

    @IBAction func handleDismissButton(_ sender: Any) {
        self.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
    }

    /**
     Adjusts the center of the **continueButton** above the keyboard.
     - Parameter notification: Contains the keyboardFrame info.
     */

    @objc func keyboardWillAppear(notification: NSNotification){

        let info = notification.userInfo!
        let keyboardFrame: CGRect = (info[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).cgRectValue

        continueButton.center = CGPoint(x: view.center.x,
                                        y: view.frame.height - keyboardFrame.height - 16.0 - continueButton.frame.height / 2)
        activityView.center = continueButton.center
    }

    /**
     Enables the continue button if the **username**, **email**, and **password** fields are all non-empty.

     - Parameter target: The targeted **UITextField**.
     */

    @objc func textFieldChanged(_ target:UITextField) {
        let username = usernameField.text
        let email = emailField.text
        let password = passwordField.text
        let formFilled = username != nil && username != "" && email != nil && email != "" && password != nil && password != ""
        setContinueButton(enabled: formFilled)
    }



    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {

         // Resigns the target textField and assigns the next textField in the form.

        switch textField {
        case usernameField:
            usernameField.resignFirstResponder()
            emailField.becomeFirstResponder()
            break
        case emailField:
            emailField.resignFirstResponder()
            passwordField.becomeFirstResponder()
            break
        case passwordField:
            handleSignUp()
            break
        default:
            break
        }
        return true
    }

    /**
     Enables or Disables the **continueButton**.
     */

    func setContinueButton(enabled:Bool) {
        if enabled {
            continueButton.alpha = 1.0
            continueButton.isEnabled = true
        } else {
            continueButton.alpha = 0.5
            continueButton.isEnabled = false
        }
    }

    @objc func handleSignUp() {
        guard let username = usernameField.text else { return }
        guard let email = emailField.text else { return }
        guard let pass = passwordField.text else { return }
        guard let image = profileImageView.image else { return }




        setContinueButton(enabled: false)
        continueButton.setTitle("", for: .normal)
        activityView.startAnimating()

        Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: pass) { user, error in
            if error == nil && user != nil {
                print("User created!")



                // 1. Upload the profile image to Firebase Storage

                self.uploadProfileImage(image) { url in

                    if url != nil {
                        let changeRequest = Auth.auth().currentUser?.createProfileChangeRequest()
                        changeRequest?.displayName = username
                        changeRequest?.photoURL = url

                        changeRequest?.commitChanges { error in
                            if error == nil {
                                print("User display name changed!")

                                self.saveProfile(username: username, profileImageURL: url!) { success in
                                    if success {
                                        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
                                    }
                                }

                            } else {
                                print("Error: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        // Error unable to upload profile image
                    }

                }

            } else {
                print("Error: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }
    }


    func uploadProfileImage(_ image:UIImage, completion: @escaping ((_ url:URL?)->())) {
        guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }
        let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference().child("user/\(uid)")

        guard let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.75) else { return }


        let metaData = StorageMetadata()
        metaData.contentType = "image/jpg"

        storageRef.putData(imageData, metadata: metaData) { metaData, error in
            if error == nil, metaData != nil {
                if let url = metaData?.downloadURL() {
                    completion(url)
                } else {
                    completion(nil)
                }
                // success!
            } else {
                // failed
                completion(nil)
            }
        }
    }

    func saveProfile(username:String, profileImageURL:URL, completion: @escaping ((_ success:Bool)->())) {
        guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }
        let databaseRef = Database.database().reference().child("users/profile/\(uid)")

        let userObject = [
            "username": username,
            "photoURL": profileImageURL.absoluteString
        ] as [String:Any]

        databaseRef.setValue(userObject) { error, ref in
            completion(error == nil)
        }
    }





}

extension SignUpViewController: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
        picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {

        if let pickedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage] as? UIImage {
            self.profileImageView.image = pickedImage
        }

        picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }






}
```

I am really new to swift so any help would be amazing!

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

First you need to ask for authorization to get user's location while they are using the app.

[image: info plist line]

You need to add key "Privacy - Location When In Use Usage Description", also you need to enter a value right next to it.

```
// MARK: Location Delegate Methods
extension ViewController: CLLocationManagerDelegate {
  func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
      if let location = locations.last {
          let userLatitude = location.coordinate.latitude
          let userLongitude = location.coordinate.longitude

          //Send these latitude and longitude values to your firebase,
          //so you will have the user's location.

      }
  }
}
```

As you can see in an extension, I make my VC conform to CLLocationManagerDelegate, and with didUpdateLocations method, I can get the last updated method's coordinate, you can also do so, and save these coordinates in your firebase.

Also you can check for authorization before doing so, maybe you can show some alert or let users know in a way that you need authorization:

```
let authStat = CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus()

    if authStat == .denied || authStat == .restricted || authStat == .notDetermined {
        showAlert(title: "Location Services Disabled", message: "Please enable Location Services in Settings to locate yourself!")
    } else {
        //do your firebase things.
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply! am i putting the code that you provided into the signupviewcontroler or somewhere else? please let me know

Comment: You can put it on signup ViewCotroller,

Comment: so i'm getting this error Use of unresolved identifier 'user'; did you mean 'User'? and when I click fix I get this error : Type 'User' has no member 'latitude'   any idea whay i'm getting this error? Thanks again for all you help

Comment: Ah sorry, "user" is from my code, you should reply those lines where I set user.latitude, and user.longitude, with your own, User's coordinate property, you should change it in the way, how you are going to store coordinate for your users in firebase.